# Interpreting a geometry problem involving chords of a circle

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

The problem is stated as follows:

> Prove that if from the endpoints of a diameter of a circle, two intersecting chords are drawn, then the sum of the products of each chord and the segment of it from the endpoint of the diameter to the intersection point is a constant quantity.

I do not want to do the problem if I did not interpret it correctly. Below is an image based on what I understand. If the figure is correct, am I to prove that $\vert AX\vert \vert AN\vert  + \vert BX\vert \vert BM\vert=$ constant?

[image]

Comment: Seems to be correct interpretation.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, ill try to prove it if I can.

Comment: I've verified numerically (using Geogebra) that the above product-sum is indeed the same for various choices of $M,N$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch people for the answer. I haven't started yet but at least when I stuck I'll have something to glance on.

Comment: I got square of diameter as the constant. I used pythagorean on triangle NXB and XMA, sum the equation, substitute NX=NA-AX (similarly for MX), and last use pythagorean on AMB and ANB to remove unwanted variable. Thanks.

Comment: They aren't? If i look at angle N and M, their chord diameter AB tend to subtend half of the disk, and by inscribed angle theorem should be 90 deg?

Comment: @tighten You are right, I misread that. P.S. If you mean your comment to be directed at someone in particular, include an `@username` in it, otherwise they will not get notified.

Comment: @dxiv hahaha. Never knew about  @ username. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  let the centre of the circle be $\,O\,$ and $AB=2r\,$, then:

- $\;\vert AX\vert \vert XN\vert = \vert BX\vert \vert XM\vert= r^2 - |XO|^2\,$ by the [power of point X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) formulas;
- $\;|AX|^2+|BX|^2 = 2 r^2 + 2 |XO|^2\,$ by the [triangle median length](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/LengthOfMedian.shtml) formula.

Use the above in $\,|AX||AN|+|BX||BM|=|AX|\big(|AX|+|XN|\big)+|BX|\big(|BX|+|XM|\big)\,$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\measuredangle A=\alpha$, $\measuredangle B=\beta$ and $AB=2R$.

Thus, by law of sines for $\Delta ABX$ we obtain:

$$AX=\frac{2R\sin\beta}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}$$ and

$$BX=\frac{2R\sin\alpha}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}.$$

Also since $\measuredangle AMB=\measuredangle ANB=90^{\circ},$ we obtain:
$$AN=2R\cos\alpha$$ and
$$BM=2R\cos\beta.$$
Thus,
$$AX\cdot AN+BX\cdot BM=\frac{2R\sin\beta\cdot2R\cos\alpha+2R\sin\alpha\cdot2R\cos\beta}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}=4R^2.$$
Done!